# Are lit consultancies just out for money or can I trust them?

Tags: editing

I am at the stage where I have edited my novel to the best of my ability. I want a manuscript assessment and have sent off samples of my writing to a few lit consultancies, and have received very kind feedback, too kind in fact. I am wondering if they are seeing pound signs instead of a nervous writer in need of help. I wouldn't be so dubious if they hadn't used the word "talented." It puts me on alert. Has anyone had any experience of these editors?

Thanks

Comment: Can I assume you have to pay for the assessment of the whole text?

Comment: Yes, payment is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an obvious moral hazard in the literary consultancy business, but it is hardly alone in that. There is a moral hazard in the financial planning business, for instance (advisors profit from the trades you make through them, and may be incented to sell certain products).

But that does not mean that all people in these fields give in to the moral hazard, or that you can't exercise due diligence to validate their reputation and the advice they are giving you. In any field where a moral hazard exists, there will always be charlatans operating, but that does not mean the entire industry is corrupt.

From what I have read, it seems like literary consultancies are becoming part of the filtration system for publishers in the UK, where a good report from a consultancy will help you to get an agent of editor to pay attention. In some ways that should make the consultancies more reliable, since if they give out false reports, they will lose their leverage with agents and editors and thus their appeal to authors. At the same time it would be pretty sad if there were no path to publication that did not involve paying people for advice.

What is invaluable in these matters is either a writer friend who loves you well enough to tell you the truth, or a writer acquaintance who is distant enough from you to not mind giving offence. Neither may be able to tell you how to fix your manuscript (though they might) but at least they will let you know whether the person who calls it "brilliant" is blowing smoke or not.

Answer (score 0):

well it is hard to really assess this kind of situation, however, I would think that editors would not give out praise too liberally.  Many people submit stories in hopes of being the next Tolkien, but very few actually are able to.  It costs a lot to print up a book and make copies to then ship out to stores and format for electronic publishing.  If a book is crappy, they probably won't make any return on it.

If you are that nervous, let them know you appreciate their praise, but you are also looking for criticism to see where you can improve or fix anything.  Everyone has something they can fix.  If they still don't really provide any then they are more than likely blowing smoke up your butt.  I would say though that if multiple editors have basically gave you the same feedback,  you probably have little to worry about and should have more confidence in yourself.  Again editors receive hundreds if not thousands of samples from hopeful writers each day, most of which are not print worthy.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a difference between editors (for publishing companies) versus the type of editor the OP is talking about. You don't pay publishing company editors for feedback.

I would also be concerned if I'm paying someone to do edits and they don't give me much feedback, except to say how good I am. That isn't what I would be paying them for. Hopefully, since you've just sent them samples, you haven't paid much. I would probably select the couple most likely consultants and tell them you need more detailed feedback. If they don't want to give you any, toss them off the list. If you've got one that actually gives you something and you think the fee is reasonable, then go for it. If not, save your money or try somewhere else.

Another thing to think about is what type of editing you are looking for. Syntax/punctuation? Deep story analysis? Someone to check your continuity? All of these are at different levels and will likely cost you different piles of money. Be clear with what you are expecting and communicate that.